# Animated drag and drop custom Delphi component

Tags: delphi, animation, components, custom-controls, custom-component

When you drag column headings to reorder them in Windows Explorer (or drag tabs in Chrome) you get a nice animation where the other header buttons shift around to make space.

I'm trying to replicate that in a header control I'm writing. The header buttons are not separate controls, so I have one control on which I do hit tests to determine which button is being clicked. Apart from a few strategies that will introduce copious amounts of flicker, I'm not really certain how to go about doing those animations.

Comment: [`TChromeTabs`](https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs) does this sort of animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use your own paint buffer (if DoubleBuffered is not good enough):

1. Create the buffer (TCanvas or HDC)
2. Paint your control to this buffer (OnAnimationTimer and/or OnChange)
3. `TMyControl.Paint`: copy buffer to target canvas
4. [you can use this buffer not only for animation]
5. be careful with count of GDI objects

something like this:

```
type  
  TMyControl = class(TWinControl)  
  private  
    FAnimationBuffer: TBitmap;  
    FTimer: Cardinal;  
    procedure OnTimer(var Message: TMessage); message WM_TIMER;  
  protected  
    procedure Paint; override;  
    procedure Animate(columnA, columnB: Integer; frames: Byte);  
  end;  

procedure TMyControl.OnTimer(var Message: TMessage);  
begin  

  //todo : paint control state to FAnimationBuffer  

  if Visible then  
    Invalidate;  
end;  

procedure TMyControl.Paint;  
begin  
  Canvas.Draw(0,0,FAnimationBuffer);  
end;  

procedure TMyControl.Animate;  
begin  
  FTimer := SetTimer(Handle, 1, 100, nil);  
end;
```